# Zend Framework How to disable a controller

Tags: zend-framework, zend-controller-router

When I put this addres example.com/js/config I need to load a config file for JS but router loading a controller and displays error beacouse the controller dosn't exists. In bootstrap file I put a _init method:

```
 protected function _initJsConfig(){
    $this->bootstrap('frontController');
    $oFront = $this->getResource('frontController');
    $oFront->setRequest(new Zend_Controller_Request_Http());
    $oRequest = $oFront->getRequest();
    $oRequest->setDispatched(false);
    //$oFront = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest();
    if($oRequest->getControllerName() == 'js' && $oRequest->getActionName() == 'config'){
        include('/config/config.js.php');

        return;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. Any ideas?
Best regards.

Comment: If the controller doesn't exist but the request is still getting routed to ZF, I would guess that the file `js/config` doesn't exist on the server or your .htaccess rules for ZF are not set up quite right.

Comment: I know that I can edit the .htaccess file to disable route, but I wanted to hide a file, so that no one could see its extension (.php).So when I put this: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/config"></script> I want to start: config.js.php file. Best regards.

Comment: The code you have won't work in the bootstrap because routes have not been established and no dispatching has been done.  You can write a [controller plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.plugins.html) containing similar code to what you have because you can intercept the controller and action before it actually gets dispatched (to the non-existent controller and then error handled).

Answer (score 0):

The default ZF `.htaccess` will not serve `.php` files other then `index.php` from the `public` folder so move that `.php` file out of the public space.

Put it in `application/configs` or someplace similar.

You could probably modify your `.htaccess` to allow just that one `.php` file to be served but you really don't want arbitrary `.php` files in the public space on your server.